# iOS(swift) Google Signin use Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-signin

[image: enter image description]

I use google signin by cocoapods in my project, appear the picture error.
Why? I want to know the solutions. I am a noob.

Comment: Will you please show the content of your pod file

Comment: # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'LoginDemoByGoogle' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LoginDemoByGoogle
pod 'Google/SignIn'
end

Comment: Can you see that?

Comment: Please remove "-" at the end and then try. 
It worked for me.

Comment: There is no "-" at the end , it's just the "- Chongyang". Is it because google can not use in China？

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual content of your pod file and the command output as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: According to `http://www.greatfirewallofchina.org`, gstatic.com is blocked from within China.